# Joining multiple times in kdb

Tags: kdb

I have two tables

table 1 (orders) columns: (date,symbol,qty)
table 2 (marketData) columns: (date,symbol,close price)

I want to add the close for T+0 to T+5 to table 1.

```
{[nday]
    value "temp0::update date",string[nday],":mdDates[DateInd+",string[nday],"] from orders";
    value "temp::temp0 lj 2! select date",string[nday],":date,sym,close",string[nday],":close from marketData";  
    table1::temp   
} each (1+til 5)
```

I'm sure there is a better way to do this, but I get a 'loop error when I try to run this function.  Any suggestions?

Comment: what is `mdDates` and `DateInd`

Answer (score 2):

See [here](http://code.kx.com/q/ref/error-list/) for common errors. Your loop error is because you're setting views with `value`, not globals. Inside a function `value` evaluates as if it's outside the function so you don't need the `::`.

That said there's lots of room for improvement, here's a few pointers.

You don't need the `value` at all in your case. E.g. this line:

First line can be reduced to (I'm assuming `mdDates` is some kind of function you're just dropping in to work out the date from an integer, and `DateInd` some kind of global):

```
{[nday]
  temp0:update date:mdDates[nday;DateInd] from orders;
  ....
} each (1+til 5)
```

In this bit it just looks like you're trying to append something to the column name:

```
select date",string[nday],":date
```

Remember that tables are flipped dictionaries... you can mess with their column names via the keys, as illustrated (very noddily) below:

```
q)t:flip `a`b!(1 2; 3 4)
q)t
a b
---
1 3
2 4
q)flip ((`$"a","1"),`b)!(t`a;t`b)
a1 b
----
1  3
2  4
```

You can also use functional select, which is much neater IMO:

```
q)?[t;();0b;((`$"a","1"),`b)!(`a`b)]
a1 b
----
1  3
2  4
```

Comment: You can also use the parse function to help build the functional select query. `parse "select a1:a, b from t"`

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you wanted to have `p0` to `p5` columns with prices corresponding to `date+0` to `date+5` dates.

Using adverb `over` to iterate over `0` to `5` days :

```
q)orders:([] date:(2018.01.01+til 5); sym:5?`A`G; qty:5?10)
q)data:([] date:20#(2018.01.01+til 10); sym:raze 10#'`A`G; price:20?10+10.)

q)delete d from {c:`$"p",string[y]; (update d:date+y from x) lj 2!(`d`sym,c )xcol 0!data}/[ orders;0 1 2 3 4]
date       sym qty p0       p1       p2       p3       p4
---------------------------------------------------------------
2018.01.01 A   0   10.08094 6.027448 6.045174 18.11676 1.919615
2018.01.02 G   3   13.1917  8.515314 19.018   19.18736 6.64622
2018.01.03 A   2   6.045174 18.11676 1.919615 14.27323 2.255483
2018.01.04 A   7   18.11676 1.919615 14.27323 2.255483 2.352626
2018.01.05 G   0   19.18736 6.64622  11.16619 2.437314 4.698096
```